# Spark submit in Azure Data Factory

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-data-factory, azure-hdinsight

How do we integrate a spark-scala JAR in Azure data factory? I have an existing Spark Jar built with Scala and I need to invoke this from ADF's - Spark Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** In Azure Data Factory the entryFile must be either a **Python** or a **jar file**, you would need to compile your Scala source code to jar file before running it as spark applications.

[image]

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-spark